# Extending the Dirac delta to $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta, hahn-banach-theorem

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37730/an-element-of-l-infty-which-does-not-seem-to-be-a-finitely-additive-abs) question the Dirac delta is extended from $\mathcal C^0([-1,1])$ to $L^\infty([-1,1])$ by the Hahn-Banach theorem.

My question is: why can't it be extended to an arbitrary $L^p([-1,1])$ for $p \geq 1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but then $\delta \in (L^p)^*$? Isn't the dual of $L^p$ the space $L^{p'}$ where $p$ and $p'$ are conjugate?

Comment: I suspect the point is that the extension of the dirac is not the dirac anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend $\delta$ to act on $L^p$ along the idea you mention, you need to consider $C[-1,1]$ as a subspace of $L^p[-1,1]$. In that case $\delta $ is not bounded, so Hahn Banach does not apply.

For instance let $f_n(t)=\max\{0,1-n|t|\}$. Then $\delta(f_n)=1$ for all $n$, while $$\|f_n\|_p=\frac{2^{1/p}}{(p+1)^{1/p}}\,\frac1{n^{1/p}}\to0.
$$

Comment: Isn't max{$0, |1-nt|$}=$|1-nt|$? Why is the maximum needed?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to write something slightly different. I'll edit right now.

Comment: So, it is not bounded because it is not continuous in $L^p$ for $p < \infty$, but it is continuous in $L^\infty$ because $||f_n||_\infty=1$?

Comment: An example is enough to determine "not bounded", but not to determine "bounded". When $p=\infty$, $$|\delta(f)|=|f(0)|\leq\|f\|_\infty$$ for any $f\in C[-1,1]$, so $\|\delta\|\leq1$.

Comment: Okay. I get it,thank you very much (on the other hand, I believe that continuity at one point implies continuity everywhere). One last question if I may: shouldn't the $L^p$ norm of $f_n$ be $\frac{2}{(p+1)^{1/p} n^{1/p}}$? (Without the $1/p$ on the numerator)

Comment: Yes, of course. But preserving the limit of just one sequence doesn't give you continuity at that point. Take any unbounded functional, and apply it to a constant sequence.

Comment: Right, thank you very much!

Comment: As for the power, probably. I plugged the whole thing in Wolfram Alpha with the typo.

Comment: Here is what I get post-typo: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int_%28-1%2Fn%29%5E%281%2Fn%29%281-abs%28n+t%29%29%5Ep+dt

Answer (score 1):

$f \to f(0)$ is a continuous linear functional on $C[0,1]$ with the norm from $L^{\infty}$. So Hahn Banach Theorem shows that it extends to a continuous linear functinal on $L^{\infty}$. However, $f \to f(0)$ is not continuous on $C[0,1]$ w.r.t the $L^{p}$ norm. It does not extend to a an element of $L^{p'}=(L^{p})^{*}$.

[Let $f_n(x)=1-nx$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac  1 n$ and $0$ for $x >\frac  1 n$. Then $f_n$'s are continuous, $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{p}$ but $f_n(0)=1$ for all $n$].